# ipad compatible javascript library to display

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I would like to display a Motion Chart like the one in Google Visualization API or Public Data Explorer.

I haven't found any library that doesn't use flash and flash doesn't work on ipad/iphone.

Does anyone know any way to acheive that.
http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/motionchart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice [overview](http://www.farinspace.com/top-svg-javascript-libraries-worth-looking-at/) of current Javascript graph and SVG libraries. None of them have a Motion Chart implementation though, but if you want to roll your own  implementation I think [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [PaperJS](http://paperjs.org/) would be your best bet.

Comment: The URL http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/javascript-chart-alternatives/ now gives "The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server."

Comment: Edited link to working similar page, added PaperJS as alternative to Raphael.